# Gaps in the Grid layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a test page of my site:
http://hookpost.com/test/index.php#news

The problem is with the alignment of article boxes. I am using bootstrap for the grid layout. There are lot of unnecessary gaps while scrolling down. I am not able to understand exactly what part of CSS I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are using bootstrap2.2.

Use in this format,

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="span4"><div>
 <div class="span4"><div>
 <div class="span4"><div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="span4"><div>
 <div class="span4"><div>
 <div class="span4"><div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="span4"><div>
 <div class="span4"><div>
 <div class="span4"><div>
</div>
```

It works.

Comment: You mean replace the article tag with span4?.. Its not working

Comment: Its not that, add <div class="row"> after 4 span4